# Get required columns from Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, vb.net-to-c#

Currently, I am getting the tables and columns with help of GetOleDbSchemaTable. I also want to get that the given columns are required or not.

```
string[] rest = new string[] { null, null, tableName, null };
DataTable rows = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, rest);
foreach (DataRow rr in rows.Rows)
{
    string tbrow = rr["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
    int colnum_type = Int32.Parse(rr["DATA_TYPE"].ToString());
    string datatype = get_dataType(colnum_type)
}
```

This way i am getting the column and data-type of given column. Now i want to get the list or a way using which i can get the required fields in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the GetSchema method and asking for COLUMNS collection will return a DataTable where you can find the IS_NULLABLE property

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(......)
{ 
    con.Open();
    string[] rest = new string[] { null, null, tableName, null };
    var schema = con.GetSchema("COLUMNS", rest);
    foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine($"Column={row["COLUMN_NAME"]}, NULLABLE={row["IS_NULLABLE"]}");

}
```

And by the way, just checked with your approach, GetOleDbSchemaTable returns the same datatable so, it is just the value stored in the IS_NULLABLE column

Comment: hey steve, can I use IS_NULLABLE property in GetOleDbSchemaTable

Comment: Yes in the same way you use now COLUMN_NAME or DATA_TYPE. It is just another column on the returned DataTable object